# Is the IP mask 255.255.255.226 valid?

Tags: networking, subnet

If I only need a network with only 29 IP address,
Is it valid to use a mask like this 255.255.255.226 (where the last byte of the mask is 11100010)?

Comment: I would use [mask 27](http://jodies.de/ipcalc?host=192.168.0.1&mask1=27&mask2=)